# Result of recursive function in Verilog

Tags: function, verilog, system-verilog

My math may not be serving me well. I've written a simple recursive function in Verilog to calculate value of log base 2. Log2(1000) should return 9.965 rounded to 10. But, my simulation shows that the function returns 9 as the final value of the recursive function. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
module test;
  
real numBits;

function real log2 (input int X);
  if (X == 1)
        log2 = 0.0;
  else begin
        log2 = log2(X / 2) + 1.0;
        $display($stime,,,"log2 = %0d",log2);
  end
endfunction
  
initial begin
  numBits = log2(1000);
  $display($stime,,,"numBits = %f",numBits);
end

endmodule
```

Here's the EDA playground link that shows the code:

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/icx7

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems with your code. The first is the input to your function needs to be `real`. Then, it's never good to compare *real* numbers with equality do to rounding errors. Use `X<=1` instead. And finally you should declare recursive functions with an automatic lifetime so that the arguments *and* the return values do not get overwritten.

```
function automatic real log2 (input real X);
  if (X <= 1)
      log2 = 0.0;
  else begin
    log2 = log2(X / 2) + 1.0;
    $display($stime,,,"log2 = %0g",log2);
   end
endfunction
```